# Pass values to array elements of subroutine

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I want to pass some values to array elements of a subroutine. This code works:

```
Sub Pass_Values()

    Call receive_values_into_array_elements(1, 2)

End Sub
Sub receive_values_into_array_elements(A3, A5)
    Dim A(6), i As Integer

    A(0) = 12
    A(1) = 123
    A(2) = 234
    A(3) = A3
    A(4) = 345
    A(5) = A5
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
       Debug.Print A(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

However, I have to pass several variables and I want to pass them directly to the array elements. Like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub receive_values_into_array_elements(A(3), A(5))
    Dim A(6), i As Integer

    A(0) = 12
    A(1) = 123
    A(2) = 234
    A(4) = 345
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
       Debug.Print A(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

The values '1' and '2' of Pass_Values are not transferred directly to the array elements 'A (3)' and 'A (5)' of 'receive_values_into_array_elements'. You need the auxiliary variables 'A3' and 'A5', which then assign the values 'A (3)' and 'A (5)'. Is there a way to directly assign the values to the array element as shown above?

---

**Answer: No, this is not possible.**

A workaround is:

```
myArray = Array(12, 123, 234, A3, 235, A5)
```

as suggested by freeflow.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not clear at all what you want accomplishing. And your code doesn't work because it does nothing... So do you have an array and want changing two of its elements? do you want creating an array and filling it with these two elements sent as parameters? Please, edit your question and besides the code doing nothing, try explaining (in words) what you try doing.

Comment: The code has been reduced to the minimum. I inflated the example for you. I hope it helps. Your answer isn't wrong, but it misses the point.

Comment: Your updated code does not make any sense, too. I cannot understand what you want accomplishing. If you did not understand anything from the examples I tried in my answer, I am afraid it is useless to continue something... I wish you a good day!

Comment: Other languages can pass arguments directly to an element of an array.

Comment: Can you show us such a way, in any language you want, please? We maybe will understand in this way what you are not able to explain in words...

Answer (score 0):

As I tried explaining in my comment, to change an array element you do not need to use any subrutine to pass values. I hope the next testing code will be elocvent:

```
Sub changeArrayElements()
 Dim A(10) As Integer

 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & A(2), "A(5) = " & A(5)
 'then you can simple directly change the array elements you want in this way:
 A(2) = 1: A(5) = 2
 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & A(2), "A(5) = " & A(5)
End Sub
```

Or firstly filling the array and then change one of the arrary elements:

```
Sub changeArrayElements()
 Dim A(10) As Integer, i As Long
 For i = 0 To 9
    A(i) = i * 2
 Next i
 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & A(2), "A(5) = " & A(5)
 'then you can simple directly change the array elements you want in this way:
 A(2) = 1: A(5) = 2
 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & A(2), "A(5) = " & A(5)
End Sub
```

If you insist do do it in a subroutine, please use the next approach:

```
Sub changeArrayElements()
 Dim A(10) As Integer, B() As Integer, i As Long
 For i = 0 To 9
    A(i) = i * 2
 Next i
 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & A(2)
 B = changeArrElem(2, 1, A)

 Debug.Print "A(2) = " & B(2)
End Sub

Function changeArrElem(pos As Integer, intVal As Double, arr() As Integer) As Integer()
    arr(pos) = intVal
    changeArrElem = arr
End Function
```

In order to make sense, your code should be following the next approach:

1. Please, declare a variable on top of your standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Dim A(100) As Integer
```

2. Use this way of testing:

```
Sub Pass_Values()
    Debug.Print A(22), A(50)
    Call receive_values_into_array_elements(22, 1, 50, 2)
    Debug.Print A(22), A(50)
End Sub
Sub receive_values_into_array_elements(pos1 As Integer, intVal1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer, intVal2 As Integer)
    A(pos1) = intVal1: A(pos2) = intVal2
End Sub
```

Otherwise, changing the array declared in another subroutine is not useful. The array dies when the specific subroutine code ends...

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @FaneDuru its not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do.  However, you could greatly simplify '"receive_values_into_array_elements' if you use the Array statement.

```
Sub receive_values_into_array_elements(A3, A5)
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array(12, 123, 234, A3, 235, A5)
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
       Debug.Print myArray(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can see from the above, by using the Array statement you may be able to dispense with 'Sub receive_values_into_array_elements' completely.

As an aside, please try to use proper variable names. Using names like A3 and A5 are likely to just lead to trouble.

Comment: The array statement is a good idea. In your example, the values '1' and '2' of Pass_Values are not transferred directly to the array elements 'A (3)' and 'A (5)' of 'receive_values_into_array_elements'. You need the auxiliary variables 'A3' and 'A5', which then assign the values 'A (3)' and 'A (5)'.
The point is, I want to pass the argument directly to an element of an array. Other languages can do that.

Comment: @musbach - VBA isn’t other languages.

Comment: It seems you are hard of thinking.  The VBA array assignment achieves exactly the same result as your sequence of A(x) assignments.